# Difficult postgreSQL query

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two tabels

user

```
    id |  name  | sex | birth
    ---+--------+-----+------
    1  |  User1 | 0   | 2007-07-12
    2  |  User2 | 0   | 1988-05-10
    3  |  User3 | 1   | 2000-01-11
    4  |  User4 | 1   | 1999-10-10
```

And another tabel

order

```
id | user_id | price | order_date  
---------------------------------------------
1  | 3       |  5    | 2017-07-10 08:01:00.000000
2  | 3       |  6    | 2017-07-11 09:01:00.000000
3  | 1       |  8    | 2017-07-12 10:01:00.000000
4  | 2       |  10   | 2017-07-13 11:01:00.000000
5  | 4       |  100  | 2017-07-14 12:01:00.000000
6  |         |  58   | 2017-07-15 13:01:00.000000
```

I need result tabel like this

order

```
          |age    |   men_pr | women_pr| 
          |-----------------------------
          |<18    |     8    |         | 
          |18-50  |     10   | 111     |  
          |>50    |          |         |
```

with gradation by date

```
WHERE  
      order.order_date  >= '2017-07-01 08:01:00.000000'
      AND order.order_date  <= '2017-07-15 08:01:00.000000'
```

Comment: What have you tried, and where are you having difficulty?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you want to transform the birthdates into age categories:

```
SELECT id, 
(case when date_part('year',age(birth)) < 18 then '<18' 
      when date_part('year',age(birth)) > 50 then '>50' 
      else '18-50' end) as 
age, sex from g_user;
```

which will result in this:

```
id |  age  | sex
----+-------+-----
  1 | <18   |   0
  2 | 18-50 |   0
  3 | <18   |   1
  4 | <18   |   1
(4 rows)
```

We will use that as in inner query so that we can later group by age category.  Next we need a table that will have all age categories in it (since we want that in the output but we do not have any users over 50 years old):

```
select '<18' as age union select '18-50' union select '>50';
```

Now to put it all together and then sum up the prices depending on gender:

```
select a.age, 
       nullif(sum(case when sex = 0 then price else 0 end),0) as men_pr, 
       nullif(sum(case when sex = 1 then price else 0 end),0) as women_pr
from (select '<18' as age union select '18-50' union select '>50' ) as a 
left join (SELECT id, (case when date_part('year',age(birth)) < 18 then '<18' 
      when date_part('year',age(birth)) > 50 then '>50' else '18-50' end) as 
age, sex from g_user) u on a.age = u.age
left join g_order on u.id = user_id
group by a.age;
```

We need to use the left join here to make sure that all the categories show up regardles or whether or not there are users of that age present in data.

This is the result

```
  age  | men_pr  | women_pr
-------+---------+----------
 <18   |       8 |      111
 18-50 |      10 |
 >50   |         |
(3 rows)
```

Comment: thanks work almost perfect. But when I add` WHERE
  order.order_date  >= '2017-07-01 08:01:00.000000'
  AND order.order_date  <= '2017-07-15 08:01:00.000000'` disappear row without data